# No output from ESP32S PlatformIO

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++, arduino-esp32, platformio

I am following to the official tutorial and trying to get my ESP32S give some output.
[Official tutorial](https://docs.platformio.org/en/stable/tutorials/espressif32/arduino_debugging_unit_testing.html)

I can do everything but I am not getting any output. My OS is Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, the code I try to launch:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    Serial.println("Hello world!");
    delay(1000);
}
```

This is what I got at the monitor (NO FRACKING "HELLO WORLD!" MESSAGE).
I have tried to execute blink program with no success either!
The Program:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#define LED 2

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  Serial.println("LED is on");
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  Serial.println("LED is off");
  delay(1000);
}
```

Output for both programs with empty log files. Nothing in them!
And LED doesn't blink.

[image]

This is my platformio.ini file:

```
[env:wemos_d1_mini32]
platform = espressif32
board = wemos_d1_mini32
framework = arduino
lib_deps = kitesurfer1404/WS2812FX@^1.4.1
monitor_speed = 9600
monitor_filters = esp32_exception_decoder, default, log2file, colorize
debug_tool = olimex-arm-usb-ocd-h
```

Device is connected, I checked it.
I mean I have no Idea why this is not working!

Answer (score 1):

In platformio.ini file add 2 lines and it will work:

```
[env:wemos_d1_mini32]
platform = espressif32
board = wemos_d1_mini32
framework = arduino
lib_deps = kitesurfer1404/WS2812FX@^1.4.1
monitor_speed = 9600
monitor_filters = esp32_exception_decoder, default, log2file, colorize
debug_tool = olimex-arm-usb-ocd-h
monitor_dtr = 0
monitor_rts = 0
```

Something with these dtr and rts pins are not ok so you just disable them and the software will be working.

Answer (score 0):

`debug_tool = olimex-arm-usb-ocd-h`

Looking at this line at platformio.ini, I am assuming that you have a debugger connected. In that case, is platformIO identifying the right serial port?

Identify your Serial port of the ESP32 and add this line with your COM port number like the following to your platformio.ini -

`upload_port = COM3`